# Desktop capture in png format

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-capture

I will like to get a screen capture and save it in the format of png of the entire screen. How can I do that?

Could I use the Snipping Tool library to accomplish this? There are some tutorials on the internet that show you how to do this with windows forms and the image is in the format of bitmap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a little method to capture the contents of any screen.

```
    private static void CaptureScreen(Screen window, string file)
    {
        try
        {
            Rectangle s_rect = window.Bounds;
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s_rect.Width, s_rect.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics gScreen = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                    gScreen.CopyFromScreen(s_rect.Location, Point.Empty, s_rect.Size);
                bmp.Save(file, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { /*TODO: Any exception handling.*/ }
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
 CaptureScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen, @"B:\exampleScreenshot.png");
```

**EDIT:** Coming back to this later I realized it's probably more useful to return an `Image` object from the function so you can choose how to use the captured bitmap.

I've also made the function a bit more robust now so that it can capture multiple screens (i.e. in a multi-monitor setup). It *should* accommodate screens of varying heights, but I can't test this myself.

```
    public static Image CaptureScreens(params Screen[] screens) {
    if (screens == null || screens.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("screens");

    // Order them in logical left-to-right fashion.
    var orderedScreens = screens.OrderBy(s => s.Bounds.Left).ToList();
    // Calculate the total width needed to fit all the screen into a single image
    var totalWidth = orderedScreens.Sum(s => s.Bounds.Width);
    // In order to handle screens of different sizes, make sure to make the Bitmap large enough to fit the tallest screen
    var maxHeight = orderedScreens.Max(s => s.Bounds.Top + s.Bounds.Height);

    var bmp = new Bitmap(totalWidth, maxHeight);
    int offset = 0;

    // Copy each screen to the bitmap
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        foreach (var screen in orderedScreens) {
            g.CopyFromScreen(screen.Bounds.Left, screen.Bounds.Top, offset, screen.Bounds.Top, screen.Bounds.Size);
            offset += screen.Bounds.Width;
        }
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

New example:

```
// Capture all monitors and save them to file
CaptureScreens(Screen.AllScreens).Save(@"C:\Users\FooBar\screens.png");
```